# assembleRelease works only if react-native bundle is run first

Tags: react-native

From my understanding, ./gradlew assembleRelease creates an index bundle (or runs react-native bundle at the background) but in my case, the app crushes in release mode unless I run react-native bundle first.

The following is my build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing,
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInDebug: false,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    devDisabledInStaging: true,
    root: "../../",
    jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
    resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
]
```

in terminal though, I see the directory generated/assets being used for both the apk and sourcemaps. I changed the jsBundleDirRelease and resourcesDir to what I saw as an output in the terminal but to no avail.

I thought doing:

```
    ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

is enough to create a functional release apk but right now I have to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

first then assembleRelease to make it work. Any configuration I Can do to make assembleRelease do the work of react-native bundle so i dont have to call react-native bundle first?